# Can I use ''the world is crumbling" instead of "the world is falling apart"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

I want to say I'm very sad and hopeless. Can I say the following?

> *I feel like the world is crumbling.*

Instead of

> *I feel like the whole world is falling apart.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but to describe a feeling of hopelessness about your circumstances, it's far more idiomatic to say:

> I feel like *my* world is crumbling.

Or perhaps, if you also feel powerless about your state:

> I feel like the world is crumbling *around me*.

---

These phrases are usually personal, not speaking of the state of the world at large. If you are troubled by current events instead of something specific in your life, you might try one of the following instead:

> The world's going to hell in a handbag.

> Things aren't as good as they used to be.

> It's crazy out there.

And, of course:

> Everything's gone to sh*t.